# Where on Stack Exchange should I ask whether the streets in Ireland in 1955 were "end-on to hills" more often than those in England?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

In the 1955 Philip Larkin poem "The Importance of Elsewhere", it reads:

> Their draughty streets, end-on to hills, the faint
> Archaic smell of dockland,  like a stable,
> The herring-hawker's cry, dwindling, went
> To prove me separate, not unworkable.
>
> Living in England has no such excuse:

Here's a link to the whole twelve-line poem (due to misprinting on the website, the period that should be at the end of the fourth line is missing, but apart from that it is correct):
https://allpoetry.com/The-Importance-Of-Elsewhere

So my question is: where on Stack Exchange should I ask whether it's true, as a matter of plain fact, that streets in Ireland in 1955 were end-on to hills, more often than those in England?

Answer (score 17):

There are two different options: You can ask either at History.SE, or Literature.SE.

Since your question originates from a literary work - a poem - it is as such on-topic for us at Literature Stack Exchange. We have a [[historical-context](https://literature.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/historical-context)] tag that would be applicable when asking about the accuracy of historical elements in literary works.

When asking purely about historical facts, History.SE should be an appropriate choice. I'm slightly less familiar with their policies, but your proposed question looks on-topic there.

Comment: If you are unsure about a sites exact scope, please check out their help center to get a better understanding. If after reading that you are still unsure you could ask on their site specific meta if your question would be on-topic.

Comment: +1 Your answer is useful. Thanks for the "historical-context" tag idea. I posted the question on Literature just now and I used the tag.